# Using a CameraOverlayView with Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use a `CameraOverLayView` with a `UIImagePickerController` using Storyboards in XCode.
In the storyboard, `CameraViewController` Segues to `ImagePickerController`, which has a `CameraOverlayView` in it.

In my `CameraViewController` implementation file, I have this code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    controller.delegate = self;
    //Here's where I need to assign the CameraOverlayView 
    //the view defined in my Storyboard        
}
```

Programmatically, I can create a new `CameraOverlayView` instance and assign it to `controller.cameraOverlayView`, but is it possible to use the view created in the storyboard as part of the `ImagePickerController` Scene, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `UIImagePickerController` does not have an outlet for `cameraOverlayView`. Your best bet is to create your own outlet referencing the view that you want to use as an overlay and assign it to the `destinationViewController` in `prepareForSegue:`.

Alternatively, you can embed the `UIImagePickerController` in a container view and just put your overlay view on top of the container view manually. The effect will be the same and you get more control over the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourOverlayView"];
```

And then assign it to the UIImagePickerController instance ?

I think this way you can still enjoy the benefits of editing with storyboard.